# ExpressionEngine ordering entries inside of a category tag

Tags: html, content-management-system, expressionengine

I have a blog where I display recent posts in my sidebar. I use this code to get all of my entries

```
{exp:channel:categories style="linear" category_group="2"}
     {exp:channel:entries channel="article" category="{category_id}" orderby="entry_date" sort="desc" dynamic="off"}
        <li><a href="{site_url}{category_url_title}/{url_title}">{title}</a></li>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

This works to display my entries, but the ordering is in correct. It displays the order of the entries in order of the categories.

How can I ignore the category order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't with that loop as its going to process it by category first and foremost, then the entries in that category, I would think this would work:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="article" category_group="2" orderby="entry_date" sort="desc" dynamic="off"}
    <li>
        <a href="{site_url}{categories}{category_url_title}{/categories}/{url_title}">{title}</a>
    </li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Assuming the entry is only classified in one category, you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: if it isn't classified in one category, you can limit to 1 by adding the limit parameter. {categories limit="1"}...{/categories}

Answer (score 0):

> It displays the order of the entries in order of the categories.

Can you elaborate on this with an example? I'm not sure I understand how entries in a single category can be ordered by category.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have multiple entries in multiple categories. So lets say I have cat1, cat2, and cat3. My entries are ordered depending on the category order. So entries are ordered by date in descending order in cat1, then ordered by date in descending order in cat2, and so on.